# Update textarea content tinymce in asp net mvc view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ExampleClass model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try{
            model.WriteToDocFile(model.HtmlContent, byteLimit);                  
            TempData["message"] = "File has been successfully saved.";
        } catch {
            TempData["message"] = "Cant save file. Have some trouble with system.";
        }
    } else {
        TempData["message"] = "Cant save file. Have some trouble with model.";
    }            
    return View(model);
}
```

View in which displays tinymce editor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Editor"))
{
    <button id="saveDocBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg" style="background-color:green;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Save boxdoc">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
    </button>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.PathToFile)
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.DocTitle, new { id="docName"})
    <div>
        <!-- This will contain your HtmlContent and use the TinyMCE editor-->            
        @Html.TextAreaFor(o => o.HtmlContent, new { rows = 17, id = "tinyTextArea"})
    </div>
}
```

The problem is that if the size of the entered text more than some predetermined value I need to cut it and save. After saving and sending the model to the view the data is in the required form (cut if necessary), but in the text editor displays the full version. How to realize a mapping of valid data to the textarea ?